# Using the jQuery .addClass function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to add a class to my list items, but I can't seem to get it to work. It's a roster of the Anaheim Ducks, and I want to add American flags next to the U.S. born players. I've got the class already written in my CSS, and I've designated classes to the list items that I want to alter, but for some reason the code isn't working. Here's my jsfiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/9zosy2z0/

Here's my jQuery code:

```
$('#content-box ul li').addClass('flag');
```

Comment: Have you checked if the class is being added with devtools in your browser?

Comment: The jsFiddle works just fine if you remove the `<script>` tags from the Javascript section as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/9zosy2z0/1/.  You have to look in the DOM inspector to see the `flag` class since the items themselves are not visible, but it's there.

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems to work fine - the only issues I saw were with your jsFiddle itself (the javascript block doesn't need `<script>` tags in jsFiddle, and obviously your flag images don't exist on jsFiddle). I tweaked your jsFiddle to hotlink to a random image to show it working:

https://jsfiddle.net/9zosy2z0/5/

Comment: seems like a comment posted 6 mins earlier, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31257901/using-the-jquery-addclass-function/31257971#comment50512350_31257901